# "Unexpected line" exception when using component load rules for RTC Jazz build engine

Tags: build, rtc, jazz, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I have a component named MyComponent with the following folder structure in RTC:

```
/MyProject
/MyProject/TestFile.txt
/MyProject/Folder1
/MyProject/Folder1/loadrules.txt
/MyProject/Folder1/TestFile2.txt
```

And this is what I have in my `loadrules.txt` file::

```
versionableName=/MyProject/TestFile.txt
```

I've specified the `loadrules.txt` file in my build definition for this component as the component load rule, but when the build runs, I'm getting the following exception when it tries to fetch the files:

```
com.ibm.team.repository.common.TeamRepositoryException: Unexpected line "versionableName=/MyProject/TestFile.txt" encountered in build load rules for component "MyComponent"
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.internal.load.LoadRule.getRules(LoadRule.java:176)
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.internal.load.LoadRule.addLoadRules(LoadRule.java:101)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.scm.ComponentLoadRules.getLoadRules(ComponentLoadRules.java:134)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.engine.JazzScmPreBuildParticipant.preBuild(JazzScmPreBuildParticipant.java:235)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.engine.BuildLoop.invokePreBuildParticipants(BuildLoop.java:844)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.engine.BuildLoop$2.run(BuildLoop.java:650)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've tried following the example [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v3r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/r_scm_build_loadrules.html) but I can't figure why it's not working for me. Regardless of what I put in the `loadrules.txt` file (nothing/empty string, random garbage text, etc.), I still get this exception for the first line of the file.

This is in RTC 3.0

Comment: Is this an encoding issue? Did you create the load rule with an scm command (before editing it if needed)? https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/topic/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/create_loadrules.html?resultof=%22load%20rules%22

Comment: @VonC It could be encoding... I just created a text file and added it to the component. Does the load rule file need to be created through the command line tool first?

Comment: I mention that as a test to do in order to see if the problem persists when created through scm.

Comment: @VonC Yep, looks like it was an encoding issue. I just used Notepad++ to recreate the text file and it's working as expected now. If you want to submit your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Good to know. I will still monitor https://jazz.net/forum/questions/86076/what-is-this-exception-for-component-load-rules-file-during-a-build, just in case another explanation is offered ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error is likely to be an encoding issue.

One way to test that is to create the `loadrules.txt` through the scm command-line interface, as detailed in "[Reference `>` Source control command line reference `>` `scm` `>` `create`](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/topic/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/create_loadrules.html?resultof=%22load%20rules%22)"

```
 scm create loadrules [options]
```

The [OP holic87](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318287/holic87) confirms:

> I just used Notepad++ to recreate the text file and it's working as expected now.